# Rounding values inside nested list to 2nd digit after decimal

Tags: c#

I've got:

```
Dictionary<string, List<double>> studentRecords = ...;

foreach (var pair in studentRecords)
{
    Console.Write($"{pair.Key} -> {string.Join(" ", pair.Value)}");
    ...
}
```

What I'm trying to do is print the `pair.Value` to the 2nd digit after the decimal, but nothing I've tried works. I tried `Math.Round`, `string.Format`, even tried doing it with a lambda expression to no avail. I seem to be doing something wrong, would appreciate any advice

Comment: Can you show us what you tried and tell us exactly how those attempts didn't work?

Comment: Each key (and therefore each value of `pair`) will be associated not with one double but a list of doubles. Which numeric value are you trying to print out? The average? The total? Or do you want one line of output per double in the list (meaning that the key will be repeated)?

Comment: @JohnWu The example seems to print the key and then all the values separated by a space.  I think the OP just wants to format the individual values of the list.

Comment: @JohnWu that's exactly it, sorry for not being clear. I want to print each key, and then values separated by a space, formatted to the 2nd decimal.

Comment: Do you want it rounded or truncated?

Comment: @juharr I've been trying to some time now and deleting, so I don't have records of everything I tried, however I've been trying to use Math.Round or value:f2 by parsing the value to a double, or use String.Format("0:0.00"). None of that has worked, I either get a compile error or I manage to get it to run, but the values print as System.Generics. Double


Trying to get it rounded.

Comment: I managed to pull it off by printing the keys with Console.Write and then using a nested foreach to print out the list next to them, but I'm guessing there's a much more effective way, so still open to suggestions

Comment: @someonerandom there are already two answers posted that have better ways than nested foreachs, take a look at those.

Comment: If the value was 1.225 what would you want the value to display as? What if it was 1.235?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use `Math.Round()`, simple string formatting (`"0.00"`) should suffice:

```
foreach (var pair in studentRecords)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", pair.Key, string.Join(" ", pair.Value.Select(x => x.ToString("0.00"))));
}
```

I also pulled out the string interpolation, its not really necessary in a `Console.Writeline` because it already has the string formatting as an overload.  Feel free to add it back in, my solution just makes it more compatible with earlier versions of C#

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6nItNd)

Comment: @someonerandom if my answer solved your issue make sure you upvote and mark as the answer.  This will help people in the future find the same solution.  The other answer is good too and deserves an upvote.

Comment: I just marked it as an answer- apologies, new to actually posting here. As for upvotes- I did, however I got a message that due to me having no points yet, my upvotes won't actually show.

Answer (score 0):

using it:

```
Console.Write($"{pair.Key} -> {string.Join(" ", pair.Value.Select(s=>Math.Round(s,2) ) )}");
```

Comment: I tried this too earlier, it doesn't work for some reason. It runs fine, but the values still print 1 digit after the decimal.

Comment: becuase math.round return a double, and 1.90 = 1.9 for example  .... the solution by maccettura using string.format it is very nice because round and print two decimals...